# Bootstrap Navbar Expands when Window gets smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umyCU.png)

[Smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxyTO.png)

My bootstrap 3.0 navbar expands when the window gets to mobile sizes. I've included pictures of the two views above and where the issue is.

I am trying to get my navbar to not expand when the screen gets smaller and cover part of my page.

It may have something to do with the search bar and the buttons near it. I managed to get the search form stay the same size when it expanded across the entire screen behind the sidebar before.

Any help would be great.

HTML

`

```
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="margin-left: -20px">GCImage</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="navbar-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" align="right" ng-model="nav.keyword" uib-popover="Not Implemented Yet" popover-placement="bottom" popover-trigger="focus">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" align="right" uib-popover="Not Implemented Yet" popover-placement="bottom" popover-trigger="focus">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="underConstruction.html"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

CSS

```
.panel-green {
    border-color: #5cb85c;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.panel-orange {
    border-color: #ff7e47;
    background-color: #ff7e47;
    color: #ffffff;
}

 .shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 3px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 3px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 3px #ccc;
}

.panel-footer {
    color: #000000;
}

.btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 .btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: white;
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
}
.body{
    margin-left:175px
}

     .navbar .navbar-form{
        padding: 0 15px;
        border: 0;
         -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
}
.box{
border-radius:0;
}



.navbar-collapse.collapse{
   display: block !important;
}

.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav{
  float: left !important;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child{
  margin-right: -15px !important;
 }

.navbar-right{
  float: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the icons are wrapping underneath the search bar

I played around with your code a little and came up with a solution, however the icons eventually wrap when the screen gets really small (less than 250px wide)

Try changing this code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" align="right" uib-popover="Not Implemented Yet" popover-placement="bottom" popover-trigger="focus">
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="underConstruction.html"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></a>
```

To this code:

```
<div class="icons">
<ul class="icon-list">
<li class="icon">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" align="right" uib-popover="Not Implemented Yet" popover-placement="bottom" popover-trigger="focus">
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
</li>
<li class="icon">
<a class="btn btn-default" href="underConstruction.html"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></a>
</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And add this to your stylesheet:

```
.icons {
float: right;
}

ul.icon-list {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
}

li.icon {
display: inline;
list-style: none;
}

.form-group {
display: inline-block !important;
}
```

This solution isn't perfect, and could be improved (make a backup of your old code before trying this)

Comment: It doesnt expand as much anymore and the buttons dont wrap, but there is still does a little bit. http://imgur.com/yMKRFvq

Comment: I used the other answer as well in conjunction with your solution and it seems as if it works! thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you eventually fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
.navbar-header{
   display: inline-block; or display: inline-block!important;
}
```

in your stylesheet. I hope this is what you expect. :)

Comment: This works well with the solution in the first answer! Thanks!

Comment: @TreynorMerrillWolfe mark the correct answer please. It might be helpful to somebody